# Make a list of layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm working with the javascript library OpenLayers 3.0. I try to have the listing of the layers of my map.

If I do

`console.log(map.getLayers());`

I've got the array [a] my four layers :

[image]

But I don't find in that, the name of my layers.

How can I take the name and print them in an alert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var layers = map.getLayers();
var length = layers.getLength();
for (var i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    console.log(layers.item(i).get('name'));
}
```

Comment: It's perfect, thank you, the good code is : `map.getLayers().item(i).get('name')`

Answer (score 1):

```
map.getLayers().getArray()
```

will give you all your layers

if the name of your attribute is name, then for the first element of you list of layers:

```
 map.getLayers().getArray()[0].get('name')
```

Comment: Thank you juls, but if I do that Mozilla say :"TypeError: map.getLayers(...).getArray[0] is undefined"

Comment: what version of ol3 are you using, and is your var 'map' global?